# Jquery Clone Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to duplicate a div while clicking on a button. But when i click on the button the div appears, page refreshes and div removed.
Here is my jscript code:

```
$("#button").click(function () {

        $('.duplicater').clone().insertAfter(".duplicater");

    });
```

Here is my html code

```
<div id="duplicater" class="duplicater">
The text goes here
</div>

<button id="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Add More</button>
```

i want if the user clicks on the button the div appears without refreshing page...

Comment: Try to reproduce your problem in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) - as it stands your code is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/yGhJN/

Comment: Try [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: It works fine. Here is a jsFiddle that only duplicates one instead of the whole lot. http://jsfiddle.net/aJW29/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) acts as submit due to which it might be doing page submit, so you could try changing your button tag, from:

```
<button id="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Add More</button>
```

to

```
<input type="button" id="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" value="Add More" />
```

if none specified the type of button tag is `submit` by default, so you could also try adding type="button" as:

```
<button type="button" id="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Add More</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just checked your code on fiddle 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maju/8WZsJ/)

Its seems working fine . Incase the the javascript is loaded before loading the button element please keep the click event inside $(document).ready(handler);

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function () {

        $('.duplicater').clone().insertAfter(".duplicater");

    });
});
```